# How to export data from tables with BLOBs as SQL inserts

Tags: oracle, plsql, export, blob, plsqldeveloper

I need to export data from one schema and import it to another. But in the second schema there are tables with different names, different attribute names, etc, but these tables are suitable for data in first schema. So I export data as SQL inserts and manually rewrite names etc. in this inserts.

My problem is with tables which have columns with type BLOB. PL/SQL Developer throws error:

> ```
> Table MySchema.ENT_NOTIFICATIONS contains one or more BLOB columns.
> Cannot export in SQL format, use PL/SQL Developer format instead.
> ```

But, when I use PL/SQL Developer format (`.pde`) it is some kind of raw byte data and I can't change what I need.

Is there any solution to manage this?

Note: I use `PL/SQL Developer 10.0.5.1710` and `Oracle database 12c`

Comment: You can't have any literal value over 32k (since you're on 12c; 4k before that), so if you have BLOBs larger than that you can't have a simple `insert` (and even with smaller values handling raw data like that is messy). If the schemas are in the same database why not set up the permissions to allow a simple `insert...select` between them?

Comment: @AlexPoole I know what you mean by setting up the permissions. It is sad but it is some crazy idea of somebody above me. I just have to do the work :( You mentioned that I can do `insert` when I have BLOBs smaller than 32k. how? Is there any guide to handle that raw data (I know it is madness but anyway I'm curious, and also I have to do it some kind of way :D)

Comment: depends what's in your LOB. if it's string you can try `dbms_lob.substr`

Comment: You could [`read()` the BLOB into a RAW buffer](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_lob.htm#ARPLS66738), and convert that to and from text; but you're limited to 32K.

Comment: Finally I just migrated that data without exporting, just directly import from one table to another using
`INSERT INTO Table_Name_To T
(T.column1, T.column2, ...)
SELECT S.column1, S.column2, ... FROM Table_Name_From S;`. It is not answer to my question because it is not an export but it is solution for me because data are migrated.